# Via Google ... What is this?

Tags: twitter

On Twitter I see people posting stuff like:

```
Just designed a new flyer check http://mysite.com
```

And it will say underneath **Posted 2 hours ago via Google**

I am wondering how they are doing it. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

It means they used google buzz.

Answer (score 0):

When an app developer signs up for a Twitter API key, they associate an application name with that key. Then, when that app makes an API call to create a new tweet, the API key is sent along, and Twitter knows to add the "via {APP NAME}" part to the end.

In this case, the user must have updated their Twitter status using some Google application.